# Simple way to report a bug?

Tags: xubuntu, bug-reporting

Is it possible to ask Xubuntu to fix a bug with just a screenshot and a description? Same as I would ask for help with a programming error using Stack Overflow. I've googled the thing, nothing turned up, I'd like to let them know.

I have a Ubuntu account. I want to spend a minute or two searching if the bug is reported, then start creating it if it doesn't. Is this possible?

This thing from years ago is far too intense.
[How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)
I don't know the names of system things. I just see the error and want to help by letting them know.

Edit : I just want to help by saying, for example, this button doesn't work as described. But, every time I try my browser history says I spend about 20 minutes trying to find out how to help before giving up. I was hoping after all these years there might be a simple 'Report Problem' method.

Comment: You can report a bug with a screenshot and a description. Just remember that the better the bug report, the better chance that it's going to be fixed.

Comment: "*I just want to spend a minute or two searching if the bug is reported, then start creating it if it doesn't. Is this possible?*" Sure: The bug tracker is at launchpad.net

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs is the basic guide for Ubuntu and *flavors* of Ubuntu like Xubuntu. Xubuntu specific [*docs*](https://docs.xubuntu.org/contributors/qa-bugs.html) provide little more. You can use IRC to contact Xubuntu *devs* and *teams* (*patience is required, volunteers maybe elsewhere in the world when you ask*), and release matters as the *development* release will get most attention. Some *flavors* do provide *discourse* reports that can be seen as somewhat *easy*, alas Xubuntu doesn't have such a forum/site.

Comment: *Same as I would ask for help with a programming error using Stack Overflow* - With a screenshot?  The code for a [mcve]  goes in `code formatting`, unless you're using a visual language like LabVIEW where the program can't be represented by text.  I don't remember what markdown launchpad supports, but hopefully something like SO with triple backticks to start/end a code block, or an HTML `<pre>` block. A screenshot is only appropriate if the problem is something graphical, like if you're programming a GUI, or asking about syntax highlighting or something, and then only for the output not code

Comment: @Artur Meinild Great! Where?

Comment: @user535733 Thank you. Been there. That page doesn't have a 'Report Problem' type button to start me off

Comment: @guiverc Thank you. I've read the start of this and I don't have a crash. I have a Launchpad account and bug I can see in xubuntu, not firexfox or other app. No time for learning IRC :D

Comment: @PeterCordes  Thank you. I meant asking about a programming bug here takes a minute; copy paste the code and ask the question. That's what I want for a something in xubuntu that I see working wrong; copy paste the screenshot and ask the question.

Answer (score 6):

Kudos for wanting to report a problem!

Unfortunately, a report that lacks adequate information is merely a complaint.

- Some lack the minimum information to be reproducible or actionable.
- Some are misaddressed, so never find their way to the right developers.

Preventing both of those dead-ends is entirely within the reporter's control, not ours.

We can help: Open a new Question asking for help crafting a useful, helpful bug report. Share the information you have (like the screenshot). We have a lot of gurus willing to help fill in the blank fields to help make your bug report useful.

Comment: Thanks! Do I do that here? Post a screenshot with the actual and expected results? If that can get a bug reported then that's perfect!